# combining map and array of string c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary

I'm writing a code to check if a person has visited a particular place before or not.
If true, do nothing. Otherwise, add the new place to the list of visited place
I'm using map to store the student name as a key and array the store places as follows,

```
#include<map>
using namespace std;

map<string,string[]> stu_plac;
map<string,string[]>::iterator it;
```

I could not find the right way to search across the map.

I tried the following:

```
bool exist=false;
if(stu_plac.count(name))
{
    it=stu_plac.find(name);
    for(auto tt=(*it).second.begin(); tt!=(*it).second.end(); tt++)
    {
        if (tt.compare(place)==0)//exist
        {
            exist=true;
        }
        break;
    }
    if (!exist)
    {
        (*it)second[++tt]=place;
    }
}
else
{
    stu_plac.insert(pair<string,string[]>(name,place));
}
```

I think the problem is with the array of string iterator. Can you please help me to find the correct way to do this. Do I need to use multimap or other data structer to do this??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data structure like `map<string, vector<string> >` will work.

You can use `for (size_t i = 0; i < it->second.size(); i++)` to traverse the vector.

Comment: It will be also possible with iterators:  std::vector<std::string>::const_iterator vectorIt = it->second.begin();

Comment: Thanks this works, the problem now is with the compare function, I wrote it as 
       if ((*tt).compare(place)==0)

but does not work any suggesion for this and the insertion function

Comment: Try `if ((it->second)[i].compare(place)==0)`.

Comment: As for the insertion function, use `iter->second.push_back(place)`.

Comment: Usually I use a pointer, `vector<string>* p = &it->socond`. Use `(*p)[i]` to access, and `p->push_back(element)` to insert.

Comment: the insertion of a new map element is my problem now, can you help me to do this

Comment: Try this: `vector<string> empty_vec; you_map.insert(map<string, vector<string> >::value_type(people, empty_vec)); `. It means that the key 'people' now has an empty vector as its value. Because the value of map now ia a vector, not a simple data structure like int or string. You should first declare it and allocate the space it needs.

Comment: Data structure `map<string, vector<string> >` can certainly do what you want to. But on second thought, you might wanna try `map<string, map<string> >` or `map<string, set<string> >` or `multimap` for time consuming concern.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you wanted a map of string -> places

```
typedef map<string,std::set<string> > Map;
```

Adapting it for your snippet (which had *many* problems, starting with the confusing formatting...):

```
#include<map>
#include<set>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

typedef map<string,std::set<string> > Map;
typedef Map::iterator It;

int main()
{
    bool exist=false;
    Map stu_plac;
    string name = "name";
    string place = "0.0.0.0";

    It it = stu_plac.find(name);
    if (stu_plac.end() != it)
    {
        std::set<string>& visits = it->second;
        exist = visits.end() != visits.find(place);

        if (!exist)
            visits.insert(place);
    }
}
```

But in reality you may prefer to use [`std::multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap)

Answer (score 2):

I wouln't use an array because I can't know it's size, I prefer using a vector or a list, and instead of using a boolean variable I would insert and then break the loop, so my algorithm would be like:

```
    std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string> > stu_plac;
    std::map<std::string, std::list<std::string> >::iterator it;
    std::string myName("Edu");
    std::string myPlace("Madrid");
```

.....

```
for( it = stu_plac.begin(); it != stu_plac.end(); it++){
            if(it->first == myName){
                    std::list<std::string>::iterator place = std::find(it->second.begin(), it->second.end(), myPlace);
                    if(place == it->second.end()){
                            it->second.push_back(myPlace);
                            break;
                    }
            }
    }
```

Look that you can use the iterator you got to add the city you want.

By the way, I wouldn't use "auto" variable if it's not C++11.

Answer (score 0):

An array in C++ is one of the types or constructs inherited from C so the built-in array "type" doesn't have any iterators. It also doesn't track its current size so you cannot get begin and end iterators of an array without also storing its size.

Use `std::map< std::string, std::vector<std::string> >` instead.